# In R, how do I create a transformed subset of a data frame?

Tags: r, transform, subset

first question here! I'm working in R 3.3.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

I have data stored in a data frame called lwd.  The data are grouped by a factor called 'wafer', and on each wafer, there are 10 locations (called 'point') where 4 different parameters were measured (v1, v2, v3, v4) (So visualize 5 silicon wafers, 10 locations per wafer, with four different measurements at each location. A total of 50 rows).

A sample of how the data looks in R (first 20 rows)

```
> lwd
   data wafer point    v1       v2   v3    v4
1     1    T3     1 0.3450 -1.3423 51.21 15.853
2     2    T3     2 0.3473 -1.5756 45.44 15.667
3     3    T3     3 0.3441 -1.3486 39.57 15.894
4     4    T3     4 0.3478 -1.7150 44.67 15.600
5     5    T3     5 0.3482 -1.4154 42.02 15.683
6     6    T3     6 0.3478 -1.4477 38.66 15.693
7     7    T3     7 0.3430 -1.3210 41.96 15.955
8     8    T3     8 0.3458 -1.6119 43.41 15.721
9     9    T3     9 0.3451 -1.4688 35.19 15.802
10   10    T3    10 0.3446 -1.4078 45.82 15.850
11   11    T1     1 0.3412 -3.2319 37.51 15.381
12   12    T1     2 0.3450 -3.2202 41.69 15.233
13   13    T1     3 0.3415 -3.1850 32.21 15.383
14   14    T1     4 0.3442 -3.2748 40.77 15.248
15   15    T1     5 0.3470 -3.3064 35.06 15.126
16   16    T1     6 0.3453 -3.3552 31.67 15.178
17   17    T1     7 0.3416 -3.4090 35.29 15.310
18   18    T1     8 0.3462 -3.2323 38.30 15.179
19   19    T1     9 0.3428 -3.4104 29.13 15.262
20   20    T1    10 0.3452 -3.5293 40.57 15.129
...
50   50    W2    10 0.3475 -2.8963 42.07 15.231
```

For each of v1 through v4, I want to create a transformed subset that looks like this (example):

```
>v1.group
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  [,10]
T1 0.3412 0.3450 0.3415 0.3442 0.3470 0.3453 0.3416 0.3462 0.3428 0.3452
T3 0.3450 0.3473 0.3441 0.3478 0.3482 0.3478 0.3430 0.3458 0.3451 0.3446
W1 0.3521 0.3540 0.3555 0.3537 0.3550 0.3551 0.3514 0.3536 0.3547 0.3531
W2 0.3483 0.3503 0.3469 0.3477 0.3518 0.3511 0.3447 0.3485 0.3477 0.3475
W3 0.3430 0.3447 0.3462 0.3444 0.3468 0.3460 0.3425 0.3444 0.3430 0.3437
```

where each row corresponds to wafer, and each column is the measurement location ('point') 1 through 10.  I'm happy to work on v1-v4 one-at-a-time, but I imagine there's a way to spit out v1.group, v2.group...etc. with one command.  I've seen this done before a long time ago and without added libraries, but I've been unable to track it down.

Hopefully I've done this right: here's some code for you to reproduce the first 20 rows of my data set.

```
structure(list(data = 1:20, wafer = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("T1", "T3", "W1", "W2", "W3"), class = "factor"), 
    point = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), v1 = c(0.345, 0.3473, 
    0.3441, 0.3478, 0.3482, 0.3478, 0.343, 0.3458, 0.3451, 0.3446, 
    0.3412, 0.345, 0.3415, 0.3442, 0.347, 0.3453, 0.3416, 0.3462, 
    0.3428, 0.3452), v2 = c(-1.3423, -1.5756, -1.3486, -1.715, 
    -1.4154, -1.4477, -1.321, -1.6119, -1.4688, -1.4078, -3.2319, 
    -3.2202, -3.185, -3.2748, -3.3064, -3.3552, -3.409, -3.2323, 
    -3.4104, -3.5293), v3 = c(51.21, 45.44, 39.57, 44.67, 42.02, 
    38.66, 41.96, 43.41, 35.19, 45.82, 37.51, 41.69, 32.21, 40.77, 
    35.06, 31.67, 35.29, 38.3, 29.13, 40.57), v4 = c(15.853, 
    15.667, 15.894, 15.6, 15.683, 15.693, 15.955, 15.721, 15.802, 
    15.85, 15.381, 15.233, 15.383, 15.248, 15.126, 15.178, 15.31, 
    15.179, 15.262, 15.129)), .Names = c("data", "wafer", "point", 
"v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks.  I look forward to your help and being a part of the community.

Comment: what you're doing is [reshaping](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/2904/reshaping-data-between-long-and-wide-forms#t=201611100315045309636) your data. There are base-R ways of doing it, but this is often easier using libraries such as `Reshape2` and `data.table` (which uses `Reshape2`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this in a loop and use `dcast` from `data.table` (or if we need a `matrix`, then we can change the `dcast` to `acast` (from `reshape2`)

```
library(data.table)

lapply(grep('v\\d+', names(lwd)), function(i) dcast(setnames(setDT(lwd[c(1:3, i)]), 
               4, 'v'), wafer~point, value.var = "v"))
```

---

Or another option is `xtabs` from `base R`

```
lapply(grep('v\\d+', names(lwd)), function(i) 
        xtabs(v~wafer+point, transform(lwd[c(2:3)], v = lwd[,i])))
```

---

If we need a 3D array, as @thelatemail mentioned, we can directly apply `xtabs`

```
xtabs(cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4) ~ wafer + point, data=lwd)
```

Comment: `xtabs(cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4) ~ wafer + point, data=lwd)` also - don't forget about the `LHS` cbind.

Answer (score 2):

In base R reshape going wide then going long again using a different variable.

```
out <- reshape(lwd[-1], idvar="wafer", timevar="point", direction="wide")
names(out)[-1] <- gsub("(.+?)\\.(.+)", "\\2.\\1", names(out)[-1] )
reshape(out, idvar="wafer", direction="long", sep=".", varying=-1)

#      wafer time       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10
#T3.v1    T3   v1  0.3450  0.3473  0.3441  0.3478  0.3482  0.3478  0.3430  0.3458  0.3451  0.3446
#T1.v1    T1   v1  0.3412  0.3450  0.3415  0.3442  0.3470  0.3453  0.3416  0.3462  0.3428  0.3452
#T3.v2    T3   v2 -1.3423 -1.5756 -1.3486 -1.7150 -1.4154 -1.4477 -1.3210 -1.6119 -1.4688 -1.4078
#T1.v2    T1   v2 -3.2319 -3.2202 -3.1850 -3.2748 -3.3064 -3.3552 -3.4090 -3.2323 -3.4104 -3.5293
#T3.v3    T3   v3 51.2100 45.4400 39.5700 44.6700 42.0200 38.6600 41.9600 43.4100 35.1900 45.8200
#T1.v3    T1   v3 37.5100 41.6900 32.2100 40.7700 35.0600 31.6700 35.2900 38.3000 29.1300 40.5700
#T3.v4    T3   v4 15.8530 15.6670 15.8940 15.6000 15.6830 15.6930 15.9550 15.7210 15.8020 15.8500
#T1.v4    T1   v4 15.3810 15.2330 15.3830 15.2480 15.1260 15.1780 15.3100 15.1790 15.2620 15.1290
```